# CodeJam Minimum Scalar Product Issue

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, stl-algorithm

I was practicing this problem, and quickly figured out the correct algorithm, but in implementing it, I ran into something odd. At first, I realized I was bitten by overflow of my integer types, so started using __int64. That is when I notice the next weird thing. So first, here is my code...

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>

using namespace std;

const string cInputFileName = "E:\\CodeJamInputs\\d-large-practice.in";
const string cOutputFileName = "E:\\CodeJamInputs\\d-large-practice.out.txt";

__int64 FindSmallestProductOfSums(const vector<int> &iVec1, const vector<int> &iVec2)
{
    vector<int> v1 = iVec1;
    vector<int> v2 = iVec2;

    sort(v1.begin(), v1.end());
    sort(v2.begin(), v2.end(), greater<int>());

    __int64 productOfSumsA = inner_product(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), 0);

    __int64 productOfSumsB = 0;
    for(vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i < v1.size(); ++i)
        productOfSumsB += (__int64)v1[i] * (__int64)v2[i];

    return productOfSumsB;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    ifstream inputFile(cInputFileName, ifstream::in);
    ofstream outputFile(cOutputFileName, ofstream::out);

    if(inputFile.is_open() && outputFile.is_open())
    {
        int numCases;
        inputFile >> numCases;

        for(int i = 0; i < numCases; ++i)
        {
            int vectorSizes;
            inputFile >> vectorSizes;

            vector<int> vec1, vec2;

            for(int j = 0; j < vectorSizes; ++j)
            {
                int value;
                inputFile >> value;
                vec1.push_back(value);
            }

            for(int j = 0; j < vectorSizes; ++j)
            {
                int value;
                inputFile >> value;
                vec2.push_back(value);
            }

            __int64 smallestProductOfSums = FindSmallestProductOfSums(vec1, vec2);

            outputFile << "Case #" << (i + 1) << ": " << smallestProductOfSums;
            outputFile << endl;
        }
    }

    inputFile.close();
    outputFile.close();
}
```

So, as you can see, I have two calculations on the two vectors. One uses STL inner_product, the other is just iterating by hand. So what is goofy, is that for the large data set in the problem, the inner_product method results in the wrong returns, while the hand way of doing it is correct. Stepping into the STL code, it sure as heck looked to me like overflow was occuring, as the Ty Val variable seemed to be an int, which of course is where the result is accumulated.

So, what I am wondering is for people that solved this question using inner_product, what do you think the difference is? I tried passing 0LL for giggles as the init param, and actually, it did result in a different answer, but still not the correct one. Oddly enough, it did result in the same answer as the hand method did before I added the explicit __int64 casts. So there definitely is something kind of odd going on here with types and overflow, just not sure what. Regardless, I got the answer right for both small and large sets, but I just saw that some folks used inner_product, where I couldn't get it to work. Let me rephrase that...inner_product worked for the small data set, but not the large one, where as my hand solution works for both small and large sets.

Below are the outputs for each case in the problem (10 total for the large data set). For each case, there are three outputs. The first is with the hand calculated method (correct answer), the second is with inner_product using an init of '0' (incorrect answer), and the third is using inner_product using an init of '0LL' (incorrect answer). Additionally, just on a hunch, I compiled as x64 target as well, but the result was the same.

Case #1: -7839202227936
Case #1: -886912736
Case #1: -1104693507808

Case #2: 7999201712083
Case #2: 1972606931
Case #2: 1127254038483

Case #3: -1313429236847
Case #3: 830755729
Case #3: -175262903407

Case #4: -3710387739618
Case #4: 464004126
Case #4: -89730309090

Case #5: -3414920765916
Case #5: -421765596
Case #5: -82026144220

Case #6: -1271937742993
Case #6: -627423377
Case #6: -30692194449

Case #7: -1964394407029
Case #7: -1594352757
Case #7: -40249058421

Case #8: -1884282427866
Case #8: 1208215078
Case #8: -101871000026

Case #9: -4044533757860
Case #9: 1325434972
Case #9: -106048747428

Case #10: -838783451371
Case #10: -1264828651
Case #10: -44214501611

Sorry for the long post, but I thought is was an interesting issue.

Answer (score 0):

[CPP reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/inner_product) contains an example implementation of inner_product as follows:

```
...
value = value + *first1 * *first2;
...
```

There are two types involved in inner_product:

1. The type of the accumulator (deduced from the initial value passed in, e.g. 0LL)
2. The type of the elements being multiplied (deduced from the type of the arrays)

So in your case you have a int64 for the accumulator, but just int (which is likely to be a 32 bit datatype) for the elements.  When the multiplication happens, the result of the multiplication is computed in 32bit precision!

Therefore, there are two possible overflow locations, one in the +, and one in the *.  Changing the initial value fixes the accumulator, but you still run the risk of overflow in the multiplication.

The easiest way to fix this is to change the input arrays to be arrays of int64 instead of int.  In this case the multiplication will be done in 64 bit precision.